# Module defined through modulemap cannot be imported in swift file in a framework target

Tags: swift, frameworks, module-map

I am trying to create a framework which has mix of Objective-c and Swift files.

I want to access some internal objective-c classes within Swift code so I ended up declaring the files in module map (in place of umbrella header since it exposes public interfaces):

```
module AwesomeKitPrivate {
  header "../InternalClass.h"
  export *
}
```

Now the problem is in my swift code when I am trying to access it by importing the module, it is giving following error:

```
No such module AwesomeKitPrivate
```

Here is the example code:

```
import AwesomeKitPrivate // Here we are getting the error
import UIKit

@objc open class MyAwesomeViewController: UIViewController {
// Some code using InternalClass
}
```

I have also double checked the import path is set correctly:

```
$(SRCROOT)/AwesomeKit/ProjectModule
```

I am wondering is there any existing build setting which is overriding it's behavior, which I should double check?